# How to determine when the Select File Dialog is active?

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to determine when the **file selection dialog** is active, but I can't.

```
SetTitleMatchMode,1
FileSelectFile, SelectedFile
Winwaitactive,Select File - 
Msgbox,File Select Dialog is active    ; This is never fired
if (SelectedFile = "")
    MsgBox, The user didn't select anything.
else
    MsgBox, The user selected the following:`n%SelectedFile%
```

Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On that thread, code execution stops on the `FileSelectFile` line until a file has been selected. So your code will never get past the `WinWaitActive` command, because by the time that command runs, the window you're trying to match isn't open anymore.
And [by the looks of things](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileSelectFile.htm#Remarks), you can't interrupt that thread without breaking the `FileSelectFile` command's functionality.
So the exact thing you're trying to do isn't possible without true multithreading.

But maybe you'd be fine to just make a simple assumption like this:

```
MsgBox, % "File select will begin after you click OK"
FileSelectFile, output
MsgBox, % "File select ended"
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.
Could you also confirm it isn't possible to launch the FileSelectFile Dialog on "My computer" view for Windows beyond XP/2003 ? That's why I was hoping to get the active selection dialog, then focus the address field and pasting the "My computer" CLSID.
I'm afraid there is just no solution for this now.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I would assume there is some way to do it, but I don't have any info on that. But yeah, the documentation does seem to specify that you can't just input a CLSID for that command. Would have to make something custom with DllCalling. So, for using the default `FileSelectFile` command, I'm pretty sure your only solution would be multithreading (launch another script that focuses the address field and navigates for you, or use AHK_H)

Comment: Thank you for the details. Much appreciated. I will try to make this with a second script. All the best to you!